# How to check last 30 rows in database with mysql_query for last 1 activity

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on user activity so in that case i need to check last activity of a user in last 30 rows.

I tried using this but this will look in all table row but as i need to check only last 30 i need help in that thanks.

```
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE got_id='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery))
{
    // some function
}
```

This is what i wanted to know :)

```
select *
from (select *
      from activities
      order by `id` desc
      limit 30) t
where got_id = '$user->id'
limit 1
```

**AS i said** : i need to check last activity ( not activites ) of a user in last 30 rows.

Comment: Do you mean the last activity of a user in the last 30 rows of any user? If so, then you might get an empty result set.

Comment: yes i know there may be no activity of a user in last 30 row sometimes but i will handle it with other way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct approach, you must only use `limit 30` instead

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE got_id='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

**Update**:

If you want the last activity of a user in the last 30 activities overall instead, you must first subselect the last 30 activities and pick the user's last activity from that

```
select *
from (select *
      from activities
      order by `id` desc
      limit 30) t
where got_id = '$user->id'
limit 1
```

but this might give an empty result set, if the user wasn't active recently.

Comment: @deerox I think everybody was misled by the title, which says *30 rows*.

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes they did : but i only need last 1 activity not all in last 30 row but thanks it works i changed limit to 1

Comment: I changed the title but i am too late

Comment: @OlafDietsche you're update works fine but i am confused with t in the query

Comment: @deerox You must give all subselects a name, `t` in this case. But you can choose any name, as long as it is unique.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE got_id='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT  30"
```

See here for limiting your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: it will bring first 30 records but OP want to get last 30 records.

Answer (score 4):

Just select the last 30 rows by counting in a descending order..
Check out this query:-

```
"Select * from activities WHERE got_id='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC limit  30"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE got_id='$user->id' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 30");
```